# How to store nested JSON object into Firebase Database?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to store string containing nested Json object in a proper tree format

sample string:

> 152#233.69#-191.7#133.69#-199.769#AP#4#"{""pot"":4}"#TP#"{""Dp"":12345}"
>        1581#233.69#-191.7#133.69#-199.769#4#"{""pt"":4,""oil"":{""1"":""HP""}}"#UP#"{""Dp"":67890}"
>        16849#343.69#-291.8#133.69#-389.769#AMULL#4#"{""sport"":4,""oi"":{""1"":""LT""}}"#null#"{""Dis"":67990}"

each value is separated by # and  the values maybe string representation of nested JSON objects

My code:

```
var myNewLine = arrayOne[i].split('#');
for (var j = 0; j < noOfCol; j++) {
        var temp;
        var headerText = header[j].substring(0, header[j].length);
        valueText = myNewLine[j].substring(0, myNewLine[j].length);
        obj[headerText] = valueText;
     }
    jArray.push(obj);
}
jsonObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jArray));
 return jsonObject;
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jArray))`: That's an expensive noop...

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your data in JSON format and use `.update` or `.set` to save it to the Realtime Database.  You can use the function below

```
function update(node,key,value){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('/');
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = value;
    ref.child(node).update(obj)
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Update Ran Successfully');
    });       
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ron Royston

Answer (score 1):

For of the string you are passing to the JSON.parse is not correct. Replace two double quotes by single double quote.